# JavaScript file with query string to dynamically generate canvas as a png image in img src

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, png, query-string

I have a JavaScript that renders a drawing on `canvas` taking into account three given variables. I would like it to function as an image that can be referred to externally, i.e. by writing `<img src="canvas.js?a=abc&b=def&c=ghi">` within any html file it should generate a PNG image there. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a function and call it, passing variables that way.

Here's an example that should help you:

HTML

```
<!-- your generated image will be displayed here -->
<canvas id="your-canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>

<!-- include canvas.js -->
<script src="canvas.js"></script>

<script>
    // call the function that is defined in canvas.js
    drawImage("abc","def","ghi");
</script>
```

canvas.js

```
// select the canvas element in your page
let canvas = document.getElementById("your-canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// define a function that draws inside your selected canvas element
function drawImage (a, b, c) {
    ctx.font = "30px Arial";
    ctx.fillText(a + b + c, 10, 50);
}
```

Edit: I have also noticed that you're trying to output canvas.js to an img element. Unfortunately, that is impossible. Instead you'll need to use a canvas element, like I showed in my example (the output will still be an image).